# How do I install a Nest Hello doorbell with no existing wires?

Tags: home-automation, nest, doorbell

I bought a Nest Hello doorbell and then just realized my existing doorbell is wireless. Also, inside the house, in addition to those wireless chimes plugged on outlet, there is also one relative "old-style" chime on the wall, but it is not functioning (at least when I ring existing doorbell only the wireless chime rings), I opened the cover and I do see wires coming in/out(attached pic), but no where I can find where they are going to.

I am looking for some ideas as to what is the best way to install the nest doorbell, a couple of options I can think of:

1. drill a hole in the door frame and wire the doorbell with a 24v transformer in house, I bought a 24v transfer earlier for different purpose but ended not using it.
2. figure out if I can leverage the existing chime box and wire power to the Nest doorbell from there?
3. there is a security camera outside above the front door that is not working (I think), I am installing a wireless security camera anyway so I don't need it, so I am thinking to wire it to the doorbell to provide the power if it uses 24v AC.

[image: inside of the old burglar alarm that I thought was the chime]

[image: outside of the old burglar alarm that I thought was the chime]

Comment: My guess is that someone did a hack job and re-sided the house or replaced the door and in the process did not pay attention to preserving the original doorbell wire, then realized after they were done they needed to do this and used the hack of a wireless doorbell.  You may still have an energized transformer in the house somewhere and the remains of the original doorbell wire still in the wall near the door.  If it was me I would be inclined to demolish the drywall on the inside of the wall next to the door and hunt for that doorbell wire.  There's electronic tracers that can do this also.

Comment: You must be right, the house was remodeled 10 years ago or so. So if I find the wire inside the house, I still have to manage to get it out to connect to the doorbell, which means drilling a hole somewhere.. if I can't avoid that, I guess I might be better just leave the existing chime and just use an external transformer? so I don't have to mess with drywall? (knowing that exposed wires might look ugly somewhat)

Comment: Rechargeable Ring is also an option. Lasts months

Comment: FYI the thing you have pictured is not an "old style chime". It's an electronic siren, usually attached to a burglar alarm system. A mechanical chime will look very simple: a piece or two of metal like a xylophone bar and a solenoid to strike it. Like https://support.frontpointsecurity.com/hc/article_attachments/360071928953/mceclip0.png

Comment: @nobody LOL, ok, that makes sense now! So that is for the burglar system. Thank you! Now that probably leaves me no other option but using an external 24v transformer to power the doorbell!

Comment: @redlude97 Thank you, I kind of wanted to stay away from battery powered device.

Comment: So I just installed the doorbell with an external power adapter, working well so far, now I am thinking, is that possible to let it trigger the existing chime? Has anyone done that?

Comment: @diabloooo0 please write an Answer (down below) explaining what you did, then ask your other question (if it's still an open question for you) as a whole new question. As you've noticed, questions in the comments can go unnoticed for _months_...